# Is it possible to automatically add an app to system "save battery" exceptions rules?

Tags: android

Applications like e.g. Snapchat automatically adds itself to system "save battery" exceptions rules.

How to do that in my own app?

Comment: Is it possible that it's the other way around?  The "save battery" function detects Snapchat and adds an exception automatically.

Comment: I just installed Snapchat on a Nexus 9. It is not added to the battery optimization whitelist. In Settings > Battery > Battery Optimization, it appears as "Optimizing battery use". You may wish to edit your question and explain in detail how you have come to your conclusion.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've just checked again and after installing Snapchat on Samsung Galaxy S5 "Optimizing battery" is automatically disabled for this app

Comment: Presumably, Snapchat struck a deal with Samsung.